# How to use QTermWidget with PyQt5?

Tags: qt, cmake, pyqt, pyqt5, python-sip

I am trying to install https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget so that I can have a terminal widget to use with PyQt5. However, it does not seem to be possible to install without building myself, and when I try follow the instructions to build it myself, I get errors.

After doing cmake, I followed the instruction on qtermwidget's GitHub page to run sip-wheel inside the "pyqt" directory, but I get the error:

> Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
>
> sip-wheel: '12.11' is not a supported ABI version

What is the proper way to make "import QTermWidget" work inside python?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I used the sip-wheel to get qtermwidget Python binding. The problem is having different versions of PyQt and sip tools on the computer. I tested in a virtual machine with a clean version of Ubuntu, and I could build without problems. On my laptop, the solution was to create a virtual Python environment, install pyqt5, and sip tools again.